# Make VMWare independent Disk dependent again

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have just converted an old VMWare image that was created in VMWare Workstation 4 to the VMWare Workation 6.5 format.

The image has 3 virtual IDE disks that are set to "Independent". Since I am working with snapshots I would like to make the disks "Independent" again so that their state is saved / restored when I set / restore snapshots.

However, if I go to "HardDisk Settings -> Advanced" the "Independent" checkbox is greyed and I can not remove the check mark.

Do I have to convert the disks to a new format somehow? 
I did check the vmware-vdiskmanager but could not find any apparent option.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the VM running? I don't think you can change that setting on a running VM.

Comment: It's the same behaviour when the VM is running.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was easy:

You have to delete all Snapshots in the Snapshot Manager before making the disks dependent again.